# java.sql.SQLException: Client with IP address [] is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, spring, azure, spring-boot, cloud

I am trying a access **an Azure based Mysql server** from a Spring boot local instance.
I have specified the configurations in application.properties and also added my IP along with all other **IPs in Azure firewall to allow access**(like below)

[image]
Still getting error

> java.sql.SQLException: Client with IP address '[]' is not allowed to
>   connect to this MySQL server.

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: There's up to a 5 minute delay for rules to take effect.  Are you still getting this error?

Comment: Yes, I have configured this for more than 5 days now. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Can you try logging in with a username in this format - [user]@[IPAddress]?

Comment: Substitute [IPAddress] with the source IP of the application as SQL will see it.